# Соединить два массива, смешивая элементы

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно соединить два массива, чтобы при переносе элементы одного массива становились на определенное место вместо других элементов. Пример:

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const arr2 = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55 ,66]

result = [1, 2, 3, 11, 22, 33, 4, 5, 6, 44, 55, 66]
```

Я думал что можно сделать с помощью цикла, с проверкой если индекс % 3 === 0

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0)
    arr1.splice(i, 0, ...)
}
```

Но не знаю как указать методу `splice` что нужно вставить только 3 элемента массива, а не весь массив сразу

Comment: так второй аргумент splice же как раз указывает сколько элементов нужно вставить

Comment: Нет. Синтаксис ```Array.prototype.splice()```:  ```.splice(startIndex, deleteCount, item1, item2, ...)```. Я не мог понять как вставить не весь массив сразу, а только 3 определенных элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант...

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const arr2 = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55 ,66]

const n1 = Math.trunc(arr1.length / 3) + (arr1.length % 3 ? 1 : 0)
const n2 = Math.trunc(arr2.length / 3) + (arr2.length % 3 ? 1 : 0)
const n = Math.max(n1, n2)

const a = []

for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  const j = 3 * i
  a.push(...arr1.slice(j, j + 3))
  a.push(...arr2.slice(j, j + 3))
}
console.log(a)
```